# ASP.NET Core - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AuditReport> to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<AuditReport>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I am performing server-side pagination. I got an error - kindly help resolve it.

Main code - `AuditReport`:

```
public class AuditReport
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string SystemIpAddress { get; set; }
    public string AuditType { get; set; }
    public string ActionPerformed { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActionPerformedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFirstLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime? LastModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

`PagingFilter`:

```
public class PagingFilter : PagingDto
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
}
```

`GetAllAuditReportAsync` method:

```
public IQueryable<AuditReport> GetAllAuditReportAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    var audits = _dbContext.AuditReports
                    .Include(x => x.User)
                    .Where(x =>
                        (filter.StartDate == null || x.CreatedAt >= filter.StartDate) &&
                        (filter.EndDate == null || x.CreatedAt <= filter.EndDate) &&
                        (filter.SearchQuery == null || x.User.UserName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                         x.User.Email.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                         x.AuditType.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                         x.ActionPerformed.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                         x.SystemIpAddress.Contains(filter.SearchQuery)
                         ))//;
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);

    var skip = (filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize;
    audits = audits.Skip(skip).Take(filter.PageSize);

    return audits;
}
```

I got this error:

> Error CS0266
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Then

```
audits.Skip(skip).Take(filter.PageSize)
```

is highlighted.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Don't use `var` for `audits`. Declare it as an `IQueryable<AuditReport>`.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - Kindly give example from my code

Comment: @Ayobamilaye what example is needed to change `var audits` to `IQueryable<AuditReport> audits` ?